# How to get the size of the Blob object in Google Apps script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, blob

I have created a script where in Google Sheet is converted to PDF and sent in an email (via Gmail API).

Please find the below syntax which is used to convert sheet to PDF

```
var blob=DriveApp.getFileById(<<Google Sheet ID>>).getAs('application/pdf');
```

what can be done to find out the size of the blob here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Blob has [`getBytes()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob.html#getbytes) method, which returns a byte array.

Size of the blob(in bytes) = byte array's length

```
const size = blob.getBytes().length;
```

Comment: Note that getBytes() has a size limit, so this wont work for very large files

Comment: @nwaltham Do you know the limit? I haven't heard any such thing till now.

Comment: @nwaltham Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60181888/google-apps-script-get-range-of-bytes-from-binary-file/60182078?noredirect=1#comment112261635_60182078

Answer (score 4):

If we refer to the MDN documentation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/size)

Just do it like this :

```js
var sizeInBytes = blob.size
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
var sizeInBytes = blob.size
```