# How to use ungzip on a fetch in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, compression, gzip, http-accept-encoding

I'm trying to fetch a large JSON in Google Script but end up with a truncated response since it hit the [50Mb maximum fetch response size](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas).
So I'm now trying to get it compressed since in my browser the request takes only 12Mb but can't find a way to make it work, any idea?

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      'accept-encoding': 'gzip',
      "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36"
    }
});

var body = response.getContentText();           // Return the full JSON, should have been compressed
console.log(body.length);                       // Return 50Mb
console.log(body.substring(body.length-50));    // Can confirm it's truncated and not encoded

var res = Utilities.ungzip(response.getBlob()); // Error Invalid argument
```

I'm not getting the compressed response and I'm getting `Error Invalid argument` on the last line.

I tried some other ways but still can't get a compressed response.

Comment: See [mcve]. *Describe the problem. "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question.*

Comment: All of this is provided in my question, I don't get what's wrong with it

Comment: Is there a error? Which part of the code doesn't work?  What do you mean by 50kb(Did you mean Mb)?

Comment: Shouldn't you contact your server?  Could you show browser's request headers?

Comment: Oh okay sorry about the 50kb, yes it was Mb (my bad) and I was refering to [fetch response quota](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas).
The rest of the question is pretty clear imo, I'm trying to get my response as a gzip to not hit that quota but I never get a compressed response and end up with a truncated JSON.

Comment: Does the server support gzip?

Comment: Well, I guess so since the request initiated within chrome is 12MB and has header `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br`
That being said, the response header has `content-encoding: br` so maybe I'm wrong here.

Comment: So why are you only sending `gzip`. Emulate everything the browser sends with `deflate, br` etc. What does the `Accept` header look like?

Comment: Using the headers `'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br','Accept': '*/*'` like the request initiated from chrome gives me the same response.
Response headers contain `Content-Encoding=br,Content-Type=application/json`

Comment: same response as in compressed response?

Comment: Just like the code in my question :

`console.log(response.getContentText())` display the json uncompressed,

`console.log(response.getContentText().length)` is 50MB,

`console.log(str.substring(str.length-50))` show it being truncated.

It's just not compressed, or I'm really missing something.

Comment: You can check for content-encoding: `console.log(response.getAllHeaders()["content-encoding"])` to see if gzip negotiation is complete and your request is accepted by the server

Comment: Alright so I don't know if the code is case sensitive here, but in the response _in Google Scripts_, my header is named **Content-Encoding** and it's value is **br**. _In Firefox_ the header value is also **br** but the header is named **content-encoding** without capital letters.

Comment: Doesn't matter. If the header is br, then the server seems to be responding with compressed data. Don't know if it is automatically uncompressed by urlfetch. Try curl to check content length in both cases.

Comment: I don't know, I'm running
`curl -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,br" -I URL` and it doesn't return me any `Content-Length` header... Here is what I get, among others but unrelated headers  `Content-Type: application/json
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Length,Content-Range
Content-Encoding: br`. I'm lost tbh.

Comment: ok what about the response itself? Does it look like it is compressed or is it's size reduced?

Comment: No it was all clear, nothing compressed.
At the end I gave up and created a new JSON with the truncated response, I'm losing like 5% of what the response should be but it's not critical and I'm just wasting too much time on this :/

Comment: If you feel like wasting more time and your server  supports partial downloads, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Range and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60181888